# Script to launch interactive session inside Spss Modeler

Tags: scripting, spss-modeler

i want do interactive tree for my project. i'm writing code inside modeler syntax and this program to get me what i want(which i want Rots tree values) . Launch interactive session opens the tree builder, values is okey but i dont generated model inside scripting. i need just a click generated model icon (without manual) but this way manuel click. who know is this trick with coding or scripting?

i'm writing my code example;

```
import modeler.api
stream = modeler.script.stream()
res=[]
m1= stream.findByID('id68YV8NTPKIR')
m1.setPropertyValue("prune_tree", False) 
m1.setPropertyValue("model_output_type", "InteractiveBuilder")
m1.setPropertyValue("tree_directives", """Grow Node Index 0 Children 1 2 Spliton ( 
 "TotalCharges", Interval ( NegativeInfinity, 100) Interval ( 100, Infinity ))""") 
m1.setPropertyValue("tree_directives", "Test")
m1.setPropertyValue("model_name", "Cart_Drug")
m1.run(res)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to automate the generation of the model from an interactive session as these are by design intended to be *interactive*.

Can you provide some insight into why you are looking to automate an interactive session rather than just using the default of generating a model directly? Is there some specific feature that you are looking for that is not otherwise available?